# How to start CAESES free?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

I have downloaded the program CAESES free on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and unpacked it into the folder `/home/xyz/Programy/CAESES-FFW_3.1.2_Linux.x86_64`. The program developer proposes to use the bash for starting the program. I'm quite a beginner in Ubuntu and from the bash I understood that the program starts with the

```
file home/xyz/Programy/CAESES-FFW_3.1.2_Linux.x86_64/bin/Linux.x86_64/CAESES-FFW
Type:Program (application/x-executable)
```

but it doesnt't work. I'll be glad to hear any step by step advice how to start this program. This is the content of the bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
# arch:  Linux.x86_64
##### If you want to use a FLOAT LICENSE
##### FLOAT ACCOUNT DATA required only durring first startup!! 
##### After first startup, email and password is saved in user cfg file.
#ARGS="-float" #enable, if you want to start in (offline) float mode
#export FS_FLOAT_USER="youremail@yourdomain.com"
#export FS_FLOAT_PASSWORD=yourpassword
# optinal to set the LICID or NotesString
#export FS_FLOAT_LICID=1000
#export FS_FLOAT_LICID=MYFLOATLICENSE
#####

##### LOCAL FLOAT LICENSE
# export FS_LIC_SRV=IPofYOURlicenseSERVER:PORT
##### valid examples
# export FS_LIC_SRV=192.168.25.102
# export FS_LIC_SRV=192.168.25.102:8443
#####

# You can setup the proxy access data via environment, 
# this will override the saved settings.
#export FS_PROXY_SERVER=proxy
#export FS_PROXY_PORT=8080
#export FS_PROXY_USER=user
#export FS_PROXY_PASSWORD=passwd

# if you want to try to load the GTK style
#ARGS="$ARGS -gtk"

abspath=$(cd ${0%/*} && echo $PWD/${0##*/})

# to get the path only - not the script name
HERE=`dirname "$abspath"`


export FWORK=${HERE}
if [ -z $FSBASE ] ; then
  export FSBASE=${HERE}
fi
export FS_FRAMEWORK_LIB_DIR=${HERE}/lib/Linux.x86_64/
if [ -z $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ] ; then
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$FS_FRAMEWORK_LIB_DIR
else
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$FS_FRAMEWORK_LIB_DIR:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
fi

# if you have "missing library" problems, uncomment the next line
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${HERE}/lib/Linux.x86_64/missing_libs/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# please edit THIS line to define your system bus socket used by DBUS
export DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket


if [ -z ${FS_FRAMEWORK_LICENSE} ]; then
  export HOST=`hostname -s`
  [ ! -d ~/.friendship/lic ] && mkdir -p ~/.friendship/lic/

 # setup the license location:
 # export FS_FRAMEWORK_LICENSE=~/.friendship/lic/${HOST}_fslicense.dat
 #
fi

#####
# start the FRIENDSHIP-Framework with the given (script) arguments
${HERE}/bin/Linux.x86_64/CAESES-FFW $ARGS "$@"
#####

exit $?
```

Comment: This is the content of the folder /Programy/CAESES-FFW_3.1.2_Linux.x86_64/bin/Linux.x86_64:                  CAESES-FFW      flockhost_crt               jumper_bin        testFunctions
CAESES-FFW_crt  frameworkProjectLockDaemon  libqca-ossl.so
ffloatsrv       imageformats                libqsqlcipher.so
flockhost       jumper                      linux_installer

Answer (score 0):

go to the folder

```
cd /home/.../CAESES-FFW_3.1.2_Linux.x86_64
```

then run the binary

```
./CAESES-FFW
```

for further information I recommend browsing the CAESES forum, where this question was answered before:
 http://www.friendship-systems.com/forum/index.php?/topic/103-ubuntu-1204-installation/

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You can improve this answer by explaining why this will work. It is good to cite the information, but it is a better answer if the explanation from the material is within the answer.